# ¿Por qué no muestra el Modal del componente hijo en el componente padre en Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap

Desde un **componente padre** estoy pasando un **array** al **componente hijo**, para que éste lo recorra en una **tabla** que esta adentro de un **modal de Bootstrap**.
El problema es que el modal en el Padre no aparece, si quito el **modal** y dejo solo la **tabla**, los datos si se visualizan.

**aca el component Padre pasandole el array al hijo**

```html
<div *ngIf="orderDetailArray.length > 0">
  <app-order-detail [orderDetail]="orderDetailArray"></app-order-detail>
</div>
```

**aca el componente hijo.ts**

```
@Input() orderDetail: OrderDetail[] = [];
```

**aca el modal de hijo.html**

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="exampleModalCenter"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">
          Detalle
        </h1>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-muted">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="text-center">
              <th scope="col">ID</th>
              <th scope="col">id product</th>
              <th scope="col">price</th>
              <th scope="col">quantity</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr
              class="text-center"
              *ngFor="
                let detail of orderDetail
              "
            >      
              <td>{{ detail.id_order }}</td>
              <td>{{ detail.id_product }}</td>
              <td>{{ detail.product_price }}</td>
              <td>{{ detail.product_quantity }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
          <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si estas manualmente mandando llamar el modal, `$('#myModal').modal('show')`?

Comment: no, de la manera que lo hago es como esta en el codigo. Estoy utlizando Angular como Framework, no jquery.

Comment: Y como piensas utilizar el modal de bootstrap (que usa Jquery) sin Jquery?. Si no quieres mezclarlos utiliza [Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).

Comment: gracias con $('#myModal').modal('show') funciona!

Comment: el unico problema es que el modal se muestra solo una vez

Comment: dime más con que se muestra una vez?

Comment: @ AlexisNarvaez en el Padre hay una tabla que muestra todas las ordenes de compra del usuario, cada fila de la tabla  tiene un boton "details" que activa una funcion en donde carga en el array orderDetailArray los datos del detalle de la orden elegida. Despues paso ese array al componente hijo para mostrar la data en un Modal. Entonces en el primer click del boton "details" aparece el Modal con los que hay en orderDetailArray, pero si vuelvo a darle click a otro boton "details", ya no vuelve a mostrar el modal. Solo muestra el modal una vez.

Comment: y esta linea de codigo  $('#myModal').modal('show') la tengo declarada en el ngOnInit() del component hijo.